# Ajax form: Get id from form and submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm tried to put ajax form in while element, but not work.
Probably can not be repeated id in ajax form.

```
<?php while(..){ ?>
<form id="cancel-server" action="process.php" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="task" value="cancel-server" />
     <input type="hidden" name="serverid" value="<?php echo $row['sid']; ?>" />
     <button type="submit" id="ah">
          <i class="icon-remove"></i> Otkaži narudžbinu
     </button>    
</form> 
<?php } ?>
```

jquery:

```
$('#cancel-server').ajaxForm({ 
    success: function(result){
        var result=trim(result);

        if(result=='success'){
            $.poruka('', 'Success!'); 
        }else{
            $.poruka('', result); 
        }
    }       
});
```

php:

```
case 'cancel-server':
    $serverid = $_POST['serverid'];

    query_basic("DELETE FROM `serveri_naruceni` WHERE `id` = '".$serverid."'");

    echo 'success';
break;
```

Comment: I don't get the question. What are you trying to do and what have you already tried?

Comment: At what point are you trying to get the ID.  Are there multiple `#cancel-server` forms on the page at once?

Comment: I put form in while tag but this don't work. Probably the Ajax can't be repeated one and the same id in the form.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, i tried this to make workable ajax form.

Comment: @FilipET *when*?  On the submit event?

Comment: I do not understand the you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the following snippt of code :

```
<script>
    function _Submit(form){
       $('#cancel-server'+form.id).ajaxForm({ }););
          return false;
       }
 </script>

<form id="cancel-server<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" action="process.php" method="POST" onsubmit="javascript: return _Submit(this);">
    ...

</form>
```

Comment: I changed my message, but I tried this the first post before, and it does not work.

Comment: why does not work ? error in ajaxForm method or what? you can alert form.id first